# Mongoose static methods in typescript

Tags: typescript, mongoose, nestjs

I use `mongoose` in `nestjs` application. On static method I stuck. I create my static method in separate file `message.methods.ts`:

```js
import { Schema } from 'mongoose';

import { MessageForResponseDTO } from 'modules/room/dto/message-for-response.dto';

/*
  Types
*/
export type getMessageForResponseFunction = (
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
) => MessageForResponseDTO;

/*
  Methods
*/
const getMessageForResponse: getMessageForResponseFunction = function(
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
) {
  return this.findOne({ _id }).populate('user');
};

/*
  Export
*/
export const messageStaticMethods = { getMessageForResponse };
```

And import it into my schema in `message.schema.ts`:

```
import { Schema } from 'mongoose';

import { messageStaticMethods } from './message.methods';

const MessageSchema = new Schema(
  {
    room: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Room',
      required: true,
    },
    user: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      required: true,
    },
    message: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    usersInMessage: [
      {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: false,
      },
    ],
  },
  { timestamps: true },
);

MessageSchema.statics = messageStaticMethods;

export default MessageSchema;
```

Also, for call my schema, I create `message.model.ts`:

```
import { Document, Schema } from 'mongoose';

export interface MessageModel extends Document {
  readonly room: Schema.Types.ObjectId;
  readonly user: Schema.Types.ObjectId;
  readonly message: string;
  readonly usersInMessage: Schema.Types.ObjectId[];

  // dates
  createdAt?: Date;
  updatedAt?: Date;
}
```

The problem is, when I trying to use my static method `const getMessageForResponse = await this.messageModel.getMessageForResponseFunction(_id);` I got an error:

```
Property 'getMessageForResponseFunction' does not exist on type 'Model<MessageModel, {}>'.
```

How and where I should declare this method to call it as static? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you call it with `this.messageModel.statics.getMessageForResponseFunction()`?

Comment: I can't refer to static function like this. Vscode marked it as error :(